# Parts per 100 return an integer

Tags: numbers, range

I'm looking for an algorithm to return the number of parts per 100.

For example, if the part is between 1 to 100 then it return 1. If the part is between 101 to 200 then it should return 2. Final example, if the part is 357 it should return 4.

A simple division will not work and tried modulo but cannot get it to give me the right answer. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply divide by 100 and ceil the value.

What language are you using?

PHP example:
`$part = ceil($number/100);`

Comment: Warning: this works if the division is floating point division, but not if it's integer division, e.g. in Java, `Math.ceil(234/100)` will return `2.0`, not `3.0`. Use `100.0` rather than `100` in languages where it makes a difference.

Comment: In Java you can do `Math.ceil(1.0*234/100)` to force it to use floating point.

Comment: The ceil() function was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, once you're aware of the problem there are lots of solutions. But until you're aware, it can be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Language is important here but usually you can either use a ceiling function, or cast the numbers as integers and add 1 to it like I have below for C++

```
int parts_per_hundred(int value) {

// value / 100 will give you an integer. 
// we subtract 1 from the value so multiples of 100 are part of their number not the next highest.
int result = ((value - 1) / 100 ) + 1;

return result;

}
```

Comment: parts_per_hundred(0) returns 1.